# Two divs next to eachother - Expand the left to full width

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, the right one has to float right with a width of 100px. Now I would like the left one to expand to take up all the space until the beginning of the right one.

Can anyone help?

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/brfbugnL/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
        Hi hi
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    width:100%;    
}

.left {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 2px solid;
    margin-right:110px; 
}

 .right {
     width:100px;
     float:right;
     border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/brfbugnL/7/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `display:table-cell` and `display:table` to get what you're after:

```css
.wrap {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
.left {
    display:table-cell;
    border: 2px solid;
}
.right {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">Hi hi</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When it worked, you should accept it as the solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use **width:calc(100% - 108px)** property for **left div** .
2. Remove **margin-right:110px** and **display:inline-block** property from **left div**; and add **float:left** to it.

*The extra 8px is for border-width on both sides of left and right
   divs*

Check the code below:

```css
.wrap {
    width:100%;    
}

.left {
    float:left;
    border: 2px solid;
     width:calc(100% - 108px)
   
    
}

.right {
    width:100px;
    float:right;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
        Hi hi
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three options here

- Give fluid layout to your html, i.e assign with in percentage (%)
- Contract the width of the container to the calculate sum of right and left div with thier margins
- use table-cell display structure

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
width: calc(100% - 108px);
```

on your left Div. Change the 108px when you remove the border back to 100px.

Comment: This is exactly what I was about to answer.  However, if you want a fluid layout, then check out @j08691's answer.

Comment: Don't forget that calc() is still considered experimental and not supported in all browsers.

Comment: you are right @Godisgood i thought it was pretty fluid but obviously when screen is smaller than 108px it starts to fall apart.

Comment: @j08691, `calc()` IS fully supported in all major browsers.  http://caniuse.com/#search=calc()

Comment: I understand and agree with you, @j08691, but calc CAN BE USED already.